# Error running a SQL query in R with sqldf

Tags: mysql, sql-server, r

I want to make a summary of a larger table using SQL query with `sqldf` package in R.

The larger table `iterationresults` has following columns: `Truck_ID`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Speed`, `Idle_Events`, `Date_Time`, `state`, `od`, `trip_id`.

Sample table

```
Truck_ID Latitude Longitude Speed Idle_Events Date_Time           state od trip_id
TTI 039  31.70117 -106.3685 0     NA          2017-03-29 14:37:30 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70119 -106.3685 0     0           2017-03-29 14:37:31 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70120 -106.3685 0     0           2017-03-29 14:37:32 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70120 -106.3685 0     0           2017-03-29 14:37:33 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70119 -106.3685 0     1           2017-03-29 14:37:34 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70120 -106.3685 0     1           2017-03-29 14:37:35 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70120 -106.3685 0     1           2017-03-29 14:37:36 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70121 -106.3685 0     1           2017-03-29 14:37:37 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70121 -106.3685 0     1           2017-03-29 14:37:38 stop  0  217
TTI 039  31.70122 -106.3685 0     1           2017-03-29 14:37:39 stop  0   217
```

The row count is 49258. I need to make a summary table based on `trip_id`. I am trying to run the following SQL query with `sqldf` package in `R` to make a new summary table `trips`.

```
SQL <- "SELECT Avg(speed) as [Average Speed]
        FROM iterationresults
        GROUP BY trip_id
        ORDER BY trip_id"
trips <-sqldf(SQL)
```

I am getting a error saying:

> Error in rsqlite_bind_rows(rs@ptr, value) : 
>     Parameter 6 does not have length 49258.

I am not sure whats wrong here. I am new to using this package.

Comment: Show us the data? do a print of `trips`?

Comment: nothing wrong with your query.  `dput(iterationresults)` and share output.

Comment: `dput(iteration results)` .`Names = c("Truck_ID", 
"Latitude", "Longitude", "Speed", "Idle_Events", "Date_Time", 
"state", "od", "trip_id"), row.names = c(NA, -49258L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002590788>)`

Comment: There is a big difference between `mysql` and `sql-server` but you taged both

Comment: Hard to tell based on the info given, but it looks like the number of rows in your summary table is 49258 based on the error but your SQL Query result has fewer rows because of the aggregation function, which will throw an error when using the '<-' assignment operator to create a new column on a data frame

Comment: @rohitj Some more info will be needed in order to get to bottom of the problem. 1. Which database are you using? 2. Which package have you used to connect to database? 3. What is name of table?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the data.frame contains `POSIXlt` type (Date_Time column). I started to see this bug after adding `POSIXlt` to my data.frame as well.

I am not exactly sure if it's a bug or a "feature"; but I found this bug-report which explains it: https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/246

I posted there with a follow-up question about the problem.